# I have defined one variable Total_users=100 in test plan and want to define thread group in defined percantages of total users

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I have defined variable Total_users=100 in test plan and i have four thread group.
 **ThreadGroup1:**-   Dashboard(50% of total users),
**ThreadGroup2:**-  Order(10% of total users),
**ThreadGroup3:**-  Shipments(20% of total users),
**ThreadGroup4:**-  Profile(20% of total users).

I want to change the variables value only in test plan and values should get reflected in thread group automatically. How can i do that ?

I tried `${__jexl(vars.get("Total_users")*0.5)}` for dashboard but not found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since [JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) for scripting so consider using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), the relevant syntax would be:

```
${__groovy((vars.get('Total_users') as int) / 2)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Beenshell Preprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to run arbitrary code before the thread group. In it, you can access JMeter variables.

```
// Note: JMeter variables are Strings 
// you will need add some casting for and to Integer
vars.put(
   "currentNumberOfUsers",
   vars.get("Total_users") * 0.5
);
```

Then you can access *currentNumberOfUsers* on the ThreadGroup that needs half the users.